# scpaegoat: [error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.Global.reporter()Lscala/tools/nsc/reporters/Reporter;

Tags: scala, sbt

i am trying to use scapegoat in `scala 2.13.1`

i have added sbt-scapegoat plugin in project/plugin.sbt

```
addSbtPlugin("com.sksamuel.scapegoat" %% "sbt-scapegoat" % "1.1.0")
```

here is my `build.sbt`

```
lazy val scala212 = "2.12.8"

lazy val scala213 = "2.13.1"

scalaVersion in ThisBuild := scala213

lazy val supportedScalaVersions = List(scala213, scala212)

crossScalaVersions := supportedScalaVersions
 
scapegoatVersion in ThisBuild := "1.3.11"

libraryDependencies := {
  val VersionSchema = """(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)""".r
  scalaVersion.value match {
    case VersionSchema("2", "12", "8") =>
      libraryDependencies.value ++ Seq(
      "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3",
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.1.0" % Test,
      "io.gatling.highcharts" % "gatling-charts-highcharts" % "3.3.1" % "test",
      "io.gatling" % "gatling-test-framework" % "3.3.1" % "test")
    case VersionSchema("2", "13", "1") =>
  libraryDependencies.value ++ Seq(
 "co.pragmati" %% "swagger-ui-akka-http" % "1.3.0"
  ,"com.sksamuel.scapegoat" %% "scalac-scapegoat-plugin"%"1.3.11"
  )
  }
  }
```

when i run the scapegoat command in my sbt i am getting following exception

```
[error] ## Exception when compiling 46 sources to /home/sara/git/gitinterpret/interpret/target/scala-2.13/scapegoat-classes
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global.reporter()Lscala/tools/nsc/reporters/Reporter;
[error] com.sksamuel.scapegoat.ScapegoatComponent$$anon$1.run(plugin.scala:172)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1506)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1490)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1482)
[error] scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1614)
[error] xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:130)
[error] xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:105)
[error] xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:31)
[error] java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error] java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error] java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error] java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:237)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:111)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:90)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
[error] scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:133)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:73)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:116)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:307)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileInternal$1$adapted(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:307)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.doCompile(Incremental.scala:106)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$4(Incremental.scala:87)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.recompileClasses(IncrementalCommon.scala:116)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(IncrementalCommon.scala:63)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.$anonfun$compile$3(Incremental.scala:89)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:134)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:80)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:67)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileInternal(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:311)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.$anonfun$compileIncrementally$1(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:269)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.handleCompilationError(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:159)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:238)
[error] sbt.internal.inc.IncrementalCompilerImpl.compile(IncrementalCompilerImpl.scala:69)
[error] sbt.Defaults$.compileIncrementalTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:1549)
[error] sbt.Defaults$.$anonfun$compileIncrementalTask$1(Defaults.scala:1523)
[error] scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error] sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error] sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error] sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error] sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error] sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error] sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error] sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error] sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
[error] java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
[error] java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
[error]            
[error] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.tools.nsc.Global.reporter()Lscala/tools/nsc/reporters/Reporter;
[error]     at com.sksamuel.scapegoat.ScapegoatComponent$$anon$1.run(plugin.scala:172)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1506)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1490)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1482)
[error]     at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1614)
[error]     at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:130)
[error]     at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:105)
[error]     at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:31)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
[error]     at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:237)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:111)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:90)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.$anonfun$compile$3(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:82)
[error]     at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.timed(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:133)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compileScala$1(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:73)
[error]     at sbt.internal.inc.MixedAnalyzingCompiler.compile(MixedAnalyzingCompiler.scala:116)
```

Comment: If you check on [**maven repository**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sksamuel.scapegoat/scalac-scapegoat-plugin) you will see that the `1.3.11` version of **scapegoat** was not cross-published for specific binary versions of the compiler and didn't support `2.13.1`, so you need to use at lest `1.4.0` which was the first one to support `2.13.1`, or even better upgrade to `1.4.6` and **Scala** to `2.13.3` to be update.